# The best way to store clicks and views statistics?

Tags: mysql, xml, statistics, store

I have some items and I want to store statistics like daily clicks and the traffic source of the page and I want to store these statistics for 100`s of items. Based on what stats I will save I want to be able to generate charts with the clicks of each day (like on google analytics) and to show the number of clicks from each traffic source.

I'm not a specialist, but I'm thinking to store statistics in a mysql table for a single day then write them in multiple .xml files. I have a slow, cheap server and I`m searching for the best method, please help me!

These "items" are embedded in other websites. I control these items using php

Comment: It might help us to answer your question if you told us why you couldn't just use Google Analytics for this. It has [a great API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/) which you can use to extract and present data however you want, without having to worry about storing it yourself.

Comment: these items are embedded in another websites

Answer (score 0):

Since this items are embedded in other websites storing this infos / request is a NO GO.
This means you either need to install and setup mysql on this other websites, which is unlikely.
Or you connect to a remote mysql .. which is quite expensive for each request.
Especially when you say yourself, that you only have a "cheap" server.
Additionally you risk bringing the websites with the embedded items down, when your mysql server fails.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use google analytics to track the visited pages correctly instead of developing one.
It will show you daily, country wise visitors.